# Visual Studio crashes when opening project

Tags: windows, windows-10, node.js, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Full disclosure, I'm answering this question myself because I looked for the answer for 4 hours and couldn't find it, and eventually figured it out myself. So hopefully if someone else has this issue, this can help them.

When Visual Studio opens a project, it closes with no error message.

Opening the Event Viewer shows a single Error event, with the source of .NET Runtime. The error event looks like this:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: System.InvalidOperationException: Controller terminated before accepting connections. Exit code: 9 (NodeInvalidArgument).
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.NodeHubController.<StartAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<LaunchOrFindControllerAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<GetLocationServiceRpcAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__11`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<LocateServiceAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<RequestServiceChannelNameAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<RequestServiceAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient.Connections.<RetryRemoteCallAsync>d__0`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient.Connections.<RequestServiceAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient.<CreateWorkerAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient.<CreateWorkerAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient.Connections.<RetryRemoteCallAsync>d__0`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient.<CreateAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.RemoteHostClientFactory.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.RemoteHostClientServiceFactory.RemoteHostClientService.<EnableAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteHostClientExtensions.<TryCreateCodeAnalysisSessionAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteHostClientExtensions.<TryRunCodeAnalysisRemoteAsync>d__30`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentHighlighting.AbstractDocumentHighlightsService.<GetDocumentHighlightsInRemoteProcessAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentHighlighting.AbstractDocumentHighlightsService.<GetDocumentHighlightsAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.ReferenceHighlighting.ReferenceHighlightingViewTaggerProvider.<ProduceTagsAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Tagging.AbstractAsynchronousTaggerProvider`1.TagSource.<RecomputeTagsAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception, System.Action`1<System.Exception>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.TaskExtensions.ReportFatalErrorWorker(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetException(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetFromTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ProcessInnerTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ProcessCompletedOuterTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InvokeCore(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Invoke(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: You are the best! I had this same issue but it was being reported as an extension that was the culprit. so, I disabled all extensions and tried again. Same error. Configured dumps and got nowhere. Finally found this same error in the activitylog.xml and found my way here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After over 4 hours of trouble shooting, I found that the error was being caused by having a `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable set with a value of `--max-http-header-size=32767` in my System Environment Variables. Removing this environment variable entirely fixed my issue with VS 2017 and 2019 crashing.

Comment: In my case it was NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192. I removed the variable. VS doesn't crash anymore. But now nodejs will start crashing again because of not enough memory during builds...

Comment: I presume you were able to find a solution for this, but if anyone else runs across it, try setting the NODE_OPTIONS in your csproj file, so they'll be available to node during build, but not set for when VS runs.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you. I had set `NODE_OPTIONS` to work-around a Postman bug. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8656

Answer (score 0):

Removing `NODE_OPTIONS` also fixed the issue for me, and additionally fixed the other issue I was having where I couldn't open the Visual Studio Installer. It appears that this is a known issue and there's a fix pending release for it. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/587822/node-options-environment-variable-causes-crash-of.html

Edit: For context, my `NODE_OPTIONS` env var was set to configure default options for node.js as per https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/node-options-has-landed-in-8-x-5fba57af703d. My guess is that there's a clash in environment variable use which is why this is breaking visual studio.

Comment: A short explanation what NODE_OPTION is supposed to do would benefit your answer (to know the changes when its removed).